# What do "<>" symbols mean in TortoiseHG Workbench after author name?

Tags: tortoisehg

I noticed symbols "<>" after author name in TortoiseHG Workbench:
[image: TortoiseHG Workbench screen part]

What does it mean?

Comment: There should be email inside `<>`, however, the address is probably empty.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that. Thanks!